# I read Pro ASP .NET MVC 2 Framework - anything else for AJAX in MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I read [Pro ASP .NET MVC 2 Framework](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430228865) to try and learn the ASP .NET MVC Framework, but I'm really struggling with Ajax in MVC even after going over that chapter again and again.  I seem to have a decent grasp on MVC 2 without Ajax.  I used the Ajax controls from ASP .NET (non-MVC) and am used to user controls in update panels.  I have somewhat complicated objects with nested sets of objects on my website, and trying to update them from the client side and keep their nested array indexes ordered is killing my brain.  Having little familiarity with web scripting in general and Javascript / jQuery / JSON in specific isn't helping.

Is there anything else I could read that might help me get a better grasp of Ajax in MVC?  Is Ajax poorly supported in MVC 2, or am I just struggling because I have huge holes in my understanding of the web due to the WebForms-ish style of the old ASP .NET?  Hoping for the latter . . . my own ignorance can be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Were in the same boat, Ive been away from scripting too long and its caused me the same sort of challenges. At this point its more-so about getting a firm understanding of JS/jQuery/AJAX independent from MVC.

There are a few books I can suggest, I am sure you can find similar threads on SO.

Wrox Professional Ajax, 2nd Edition (Programmer to Programmer)
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Ajax-2nd-Programmer/dp/0470109491/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470109491)

jQuery in Action (2nd Edition)
[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Action-Second-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1935182323/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935182323)

Javascript (Missing Manual)
[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Missing-David-Sawyer-McFarland/dp/0596515898/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596515898)

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I got a brief tutorial from a coworker that helped a lot with getting my head straightened out, and I'll check these out as well.  It's rather frustrating to go from all the server-side support of MVC to the, "Here's JSON and JS, now you're on your own!" feel of working on the client.  I hadn't quite realized that every Ajax control needed corresponding JS on the client side to work . . . I think now that I'll probably just do away w/ Ajax .Net altogether, like so many others on this site have done and just use the jQuery libraries.